# Subclassing UITabbarController and AppStore verification

Tags: ios, app-store, uitabbarcontroller

We are building an app for iOS 5.0. I've found in the Apple documentation that UITabbarController is not meant to be subclassed and due to that we have a problem.

I need to perform conditional segue on every tabbar item and I know I need to use performSegueWithIdentifier. But I have no idea how to do this without creating a subclass of UITabbarController.

Of course I can do it but I've heard that if I subclass this particular controller, my app won't pass AppStore verification. Is it true?

Answer (score 0):

Questions asking "Will this get into the AppStore" cannot be answered by us. Only Apple knows whether or not your app will be approved.

However, it seems that the docs say that it's discouraged to subclass UITabBarController - it also is to subclass NSString, NSArray etc. But it's not strictly prohibited. (Apple itself does it, for example in their iTunesStoreUI private framework.) Apps are mostly rejected for using private APIs -- and this is not one of them.

Comment: I am aware of that you can't answer me if "Will this get into the AppStore" :). I was just wondering if anybody knows anything about restrictions connected with UITabbarController. BTW, is there any other way to perform conditional segues with UITabbarController? I've found some solutions but they didn't work...

Comment: @pawel.kalisz exactly what are you trying to do? (I'm not familiar with this new storyboard-segue-whatever thingy, I don't use InterfaceBuilder).

Comment: We are building app based on UITabbarController and we are using storyboards. Some tabs are available only when user provide login and password so I need to perform different segues when user is logout and I don't know how to do it without subclassing UITabbarController.